# SQL Shortest Path

Tags: sql, sqlite, shortest-path

I have a table with a bunch of edges which I made by: `CREATE TABLE example ([FromId] INT, [ToId] INT);` (I must use a format like this). I am trying to find the shortest path between a given "FromId" to a "ToId" (ie we are trying to get from one node to other).

I understand there is a SHORTEST PATH but I am unsure how to use this in my case as I did not declare my table a SQL graph.

Sorry if this is a stupid question I am new to StackOverflow and to SQL. I am using SQLite.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: And the database you are using (Oracle, SQL Server, etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a recursive CTE.  Here is one method:

```
with recursive cte as (
      select f, t, 1 as lev, (f || '->' || t) as path
      from edges
      where f = 1
      union all
      select e.f, e.t, lev + 1 , (cte.path || '->' || e.t) as path
      from cte join
           edges e
           on e.f = cte.t
      where lev < 100 or e.t = 4
     )
select cte.*
from cte
where cte.t = 4
order by lev
limit 1;
```

This limits the path length to 100 -- a reasonable maximum in most cases -- to handle potential cycles in your graph.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=bcc0b9e350977daeb7a34cdaf005b7a9) is a db<>fiddle.